# Plotly scattermapbox : mapbox frame adjust margins

Tags: plotly, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, plotly-dash

I am using plotly's scattermapbox library. I'd like to adjust margins when I plot the map graph. Too much space is being used up around the margins.

How do I adjust the margins? I can seem to find the property or css.

```
html.Div([

        # Plot properties map
        dcc.Graph(id='map-graph1',
                  style={'display': 'inline-block', 'width': '900px', 'float': 'left', 'height':'750px', 'margin-left':'0%'}
                
        ),

   ], className='map-style',
      style={"width": "38%"}),




layout = {
         "autosize": False,
         "hovermode": "closest",
         #"title": "Property Map",
         "mapbox": {
             "accesstoken": MAPBOX_KEY,
             "bearing": 0,
             "center": {
                 "lat": layout_lat,
                 "lon": layout_lon
             },
             "pitch": 0,
             "zoom": zoom,
             "style": "outdoors",
         }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `autosize=True`?? based on the documentation that should make the size automatic to it's container

https://plotly.com/python/reference/#layout-autosize

Here you have a [sample](https://plotly.com/python/scattermapbox/#nuclear-waste-sites-on-campuses)

[image]

Comment: Yes, I tried setting autosize=True. It didn't work.

Comment: Unless you can post a bit more code including the html page and container it’s hard to diagnose where the issue comes from

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked for me as a layout.  Note autosize and margin directives.

```
    layout : {
      width : 600,
      height : 600,
      autosize : true,
      margin: { r: 0, t: 0, b: 0, l: 0 },
      mapbox : {
        style: "open-street-map",
        zoom : 12,
        //Center of map
        center: {
          lat: 42.68048701106918,
          lon: -73.78118961291001
          //Defaulted to CDTA at Albany, NY^
        }
      },
      showlegend: false
    }
```